# How to block a user from going to a given url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

In my vue app project, i create function which hides a menu item for specific users with too few permissions like below:

```
<a :href="href" @click="navigate" v-if="wikiPanelVisibility()">
    // some code
</a>

wikiPanelVisibility() {
    if(currentUser.permission == 'All') {
      return true;
    } else return false; 
}
```

So, Ok, this hide my element on UI and current logged in user cannot go to page with url e.q. `https://somelink.com/account/settings` via clicking on anchor in UI, but when he write this url then he can be redirected to this page, and here i have a problem, how to block user going to this url via writing it in a browser?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Whenever a browser hits a restricted url, test the user's athorization. If they pass, show the page, and if they fail, load a 403 page instead (or the homepage, or whatever you want).

Comment: If you are using any framework, you could look into the concept of middleware

Comment: You should use authorization on the actuall page that you want to redirect to. Otherwise if you just authorize on the click it can be easily avoided by just typing the url that the button navigates to. If you are using ASP.NET Core you can use Identity to authorize users.

Comment: Manually changing the URL in the browser can not be blocked. Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - otherwise, please explain how this is related to [tag:css]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Vue Router and configure the validation on the beforeEach loop as indicated on the doc [Navigation Guards]: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

You will have something like this:

```
   router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
     const currentUser = store.state.currentUser
     if ( currentUser.permission !== 'All) {
       next(loginPage)
     } else {
       next()
     }
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Navigation guards to apply that logic for the specific page [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

Set up routes like this in your routes file:

```
{
    path:'/yourPath',
    meta:{guest:false},
    component:YourComponent
}
```

Example from page to redirect user to /login page if not authenticated:

```
// BAD
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      if (to.name !== 'Login' && !isAuthenticated) next({ name: 'Login' })
      // if the user is not authenticated, `next` is called twice
      next()
    })
// GOOD
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Login' && !isAuthenticated) next({ name: 'Login' })
  else next()
})
```